# python - write a dictionary with values that are lists of integers to csv without brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x

The script reads a file `syslog.log` that has error messages, parses it, builds a dictionary, and then writes the dictionary to `user_statistics.csv` file.

I would like to write the integers from `key:list` without the brackets, quotes or white space.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import csv


per_user = {'noel': [2, 2], 'mcintosh': [2, 1], 'enim.non': [1, 1], 'oren': [0, 2], 'bpacheco': [0, 1], 'mdouglas': [0, 1], 'ac': [1, 0], 'blossom': [0, 1]}

with open('user_statistics.csv', 'w') as csvfile1:
        y = csv.writer(csvfile1)  
        y.writerow(['Username', 'INFO', 'ERROR'])
        y.writerows(per_user.items())
```

output received in user_statistics.csv

```
Username,INFO,ERROR
ac,"[1, 0]"
blossom,"[0, 1]"
bpacheco,"[0, 1]"
enim.non,"[1, 1]"
mcintosh,"[2, 1]"
mdouglas,"[0, 1]"
oren,"[0, 2]"
```

Desired output is

```
Username,INFO,ERROR
ac,1,0
blossom,0,
bpacheco,0,1
enim.non,1,1
mcintosh,2,1
mdouglas,0,1
oren,0,2
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  Your stated problem involves *only* output format, but (1) much of your posting deals with data ingestion; (2) that ingestion depends on an external file; (3) you haven't traced any of the offending values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to do something like:

```
import csv


per_user = {'noel': [2, 2], 'mcintosh': [2, 1], 'enim.non': [1, 1], 'oren': [0, 2], 'bpacheco': [0, 1], 'mdouglas': [0, 1], 'ac': [1, 0], 'blossom': [0, 1]}

with open('user_statistics.csv', 'w') as csvfile1:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile1)  
    writer.writerow(['Username', 'INFO', 'ERROR'])
    for name, (info, error) in per_user.items():
        writer.writerow([name, info, error])
```

Answer (score 0):

solution with pandas (instead of second `with` statement).

```
import pandas as pd

keys = per_user.keys()
values = per_user.values()
df_keys = pd.DataFrame(keys, columns=['Username'])
df_values = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['INFO', 'ERROR'])
data = df_keys.join(df_values)
data.to_csv("user_statistics.csv", index=False)
```

Outputs:

```
Username,INFO,ERROR
ac,1,0
blossom,0,1
bpacheco,0,1
enim.non,1,1
mcintosh,2,1
mdouglas,0,1
oren,0,2
```

Comment: The pandas solution does work. However, the selected answer from @juanpa.arrivillaga requires the least amount of changes.